# Graph XML to Visual Representation

Tags: xml, svg, graph, visualization

I have an XML document and want a visual representation (eg. an SVG graphic). Eg.

```
<set>
   <A>
      <B>bla</B>
      foo
   </A>
   <A>blub</A>
</set>
```

Should render to something like:

[image]

or something similar like a dendrogram.
I don't have any preferences regarding the technology. The easiest way will do.

Comment: check [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org)

Answer (score 2):

As @Javier suggested in the comments, checkout [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  Specifically:

1. Write XSLT to map from your XML to
   [DotML](http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/), an XML representation of the [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) graph description language.  You can validate DotML against the [DotML schema](http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dotml-1.4.xsd).
2. Run [generate-svg-graphics.bash](http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/generate-svg-graphics.bash), which uses [generate-svg-graphics.xsl](http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dotml2dot.xsl), to convert from DotML to SVG.

See also: Michael Kay's [DotML ant build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863915/290085).