# Visualize XML tree structure

Tags: xml, visualization, graph-visualization

I have several XML files which have a similar structure but with some differences that I cannot overlook. They are all TEI documents.

**I am looking for a way to outline the main structure.**

Take the following text as an example:

```
<text xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="d1">
<body xml:id="d2">
<div1 type="book" xml:id="d3">
<head>Songs of Innocence</head>
<pb n="4"/>
<div2 type="poem" xml:id="d4">
<head>Introduction</head>
<lg type="stanza">
<l>Piping down the valleys wild, </l>
<l>Piping songs of pleasant glee, </l>
<l>On a cloud I saw a child, </l>
<l>And he laughing said to me: </l>
</lg>
```

I would like to suppress the nodes of the same type and all the repeating structures:

```
<body xml:id="d2">
<div1 type="book" xml:id="d3">
<head>Songs of Innocence</head>
<pb n="4"/>
<div2 type="poem" xml:id="d4">
<head>Introduction</head>
<lg type="stanza">
<l>...</l>
</lg>
<lg>...</lg>
```

So, basically I want to reduce the XML document to its most basic structure. In this way I can figure out how to properly convert them using XSLT.

Answer (score 2):

**Here are some options for viewing your XML in a tree structure:**

1. Open the XML in a web browser and get an outline view with
   collapsible elements.
2. Open the XML in graphics view in [Oxygen](https://www.oxygenxml.com/), [QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com/), or [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html).
3. Use [Graphviz or DotML ant build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28972374/290085) to create your own
   visual representations.

Note, however, that you'll need to clean up your markup.  What you show doesn't qualify as XML as it's missing end tags and lacks a single root element.  (XML has to be ***[well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)***.)

Answer (score 2):

Using perl XML::DT, (`apt-get install libxml-dt-perl` if not installed),
the command `mkxmltype file.xml` returns a compact description of the
xml structure. Example

```
$ mkxmltype -lines=1000  a.xml 

# text ...Fri Feb 26 17:56:24 2016
text    =>  body * xml:id
body    =>  div1 * xml:id
div1    =>  tup(div2, pb, head) * type * xml:id
div2    =>  tup(head, lg) * type * xml:id
pb  =>  empty * n
head    =>  text
lg  =>  seq(l) * type
l   =>  text
```

Comment: This tool has the problem of not being able to parse files with escaped chars. I get lots of `c.xml:882: parser error : Entity 'eacute' not defined
    <LM lemma="perch&eacute;" catg="b">Perch&eacute;</LM>`